# Count values from range in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to count the number of values in the array. I have a code which works:

```
Range = [1:10^3];% [1:10^6];
N = 10^2;% 10^8

Data = randi([Range(1),Range(end)],N,1);

Counts = nan(numel(Range),1);

for iRange = 1:numel(Range)
   Counts(iRange) = sum(Data==Range(iRange)); 
end
```

**Could you help me to make this code faster?**

I feel that it should be via `unique` or `hist`, but I could not find a solution.

`N = histcounts(Data,Range)`

gives me 999 numbers instead of 1000.

Comment: `hist` or even better `histcounts` should do the job. Have you tried them?

Comment: I know that they should do a job, but I could not find the way.

Comment: The second argument of `histcounts`, as the documentation states, are the edges of the bins.  `[0,1,2]` will return 2 values: the count of the numbers between 0-1 and the ones between 1-2. Just define your range properly. Perhaps `0:10^3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Ander Biguri` stated at a comment, `histcounts` is what you seek.

The function counts the number of values of `X` (`Data` in your example), are found at every bin between two edges, where bins defined as such:

> The value X(i) is in the kth bin if edges(k) ≤ X(i) < edges(k+1).

While the last bin also includes the right edges.

**This means:**

1. For N values, you need N+1 edges.
2. Each bin should start at the value you want it to include (1 between 1:2, 2 between 2:3, etc).

**In your example:**

`Counts = histcounts(Data,Range(1):(Range(end)+1))';`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to point out an issue with this code:

```
Counts = nan(numel(Range),1);
for iRange = 1:numel(Range)
   Counts(iRange) = sum(Data==Range(iRange)); 
end
```

It shows a single loop, but `==` and `sum` work over all elements in the array, making this **really** expensive compared to a loop that doesn't do so, especially if `N` is large:

```
Counts = zeros(numel(Range),1);
for elem = Data(:).'
   Counts(elem) = Counts(elem) + 1;
end
```